# Huawei MU736 3G modem not showing in network manager and not connecting

Tags: networking, usb, usb-modem, huawei

I have a Huawei 3G module, model MU736, installed by default on my Clevo laptop, Ubuntu 14.04 64.

Here is what I know:

- I have a dual boot with Debian 8 Jessie (which despite of Ubuntu doesn't work with nvidia drivers) and this one works almost properly with the modem (after doing `dpkg-reconfigure modem manager`) , maybe I can use it to know how it works.
- The module is fully supported by free desktop modem manager, as listed here: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ModemManager/SupportedDevices/
- Usb modeswitch works properly as I can see the modem interface in lsusb and even the modem serial port in /dev/ttyUSB1 and I den see it in modem manager GUI but with no access.
- I tried `dpkg-reconfigure modemmanager` with no luck, even purge and reinstall didn't work.

Help!

Comment: I am having identical issues with the HP hs3110, which is supposed to be the [same device](http://www.diytrade.com/china/pd/14714929/Huawei_mu736_hs3110_HSPA_NGFF_Interface_3g_4g_module.html).

Comment: Add the output of the command `lsusb` to your question and I will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved with later versions of Ubuntu, just remember to insert the SIM card and the modem will show up in the menu and will work fine.

Comment: Didn’t work for me (OS is Ubuntu MATE 16.04).

Comment: Tried Ubuntu MATE 17.10 beta from a live USB stick, which didn’t work either. Which version of Ubuntu did you use?

Comment: For completeness: I have a HP hs3110, which reports a different vendor/product ID than other MU736 devices—maybe that’s where the difference lies.

Answer (score 1):

I found some valuable pointers [here](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/522269-HP-hs3110-HSPA-Mobile-Broadband-Module-in-HP-ProBook-645-G2-not-working?s=7d005c1c8f3f606c57ff624fa21f8409) and [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=202487#p1055397). They describe what commands need to be run, and how to wrap them into a systemd service. However, the service will run whether or not the modem is actually present, which may be undesirable. I have managed to use udev rules instead, thus the initialization sequence will run only if the device is actually present.

Note that these are for the HP hs3110, which reports itself as a HP device, not a Huawei device—if you have a non-HP device, your device ID may be different than what is reported below.

Step-by-step instructions:

Ensure you have `usb-modeswitch` and `usb-modeswitch-data` installed (install them if they are missing).

Edit `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules`, adding the following lines to the block of device rules:

```
# HP hs3110 (Huawei MU736)
ATTR{idVendor}=="03f0", ATTR{idProduct}=="521d", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
ATTR{idVendor}=="03f0", ATTR{idProduct}=="521d", RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'modprobe option && echo 03f0 521d > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id'"
```

Install `wvdial`.

Edit `/etc/wvdial.conf`, appending the following section:

```
[Dialer 3G]
Init2 = ATZ
Init3 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Init5 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP"
ISDN = 0
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB2
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Baud = 460800
```

The next time you reboot and log in, you will be prompted for your PIN. After that, the modem should appear in Network Manager and you can configure a connection.

One caveat: You will not be able to connect until you run `wvdial 3G` from the command line (you need to do this once after each reboot).

I’m still trying to figure out how to automate this:

- Using the systemd approach and adding the command to the initialization script doesn’t work.
- With the udev approach, adding `wvdial` to the rule also doesn’t work.
- Some have suggested making it an autostart command which runs after login, which also hasn’t worked for me.