# 16.04, HP Probook 645 G2, not working broadband module hs3110

Tags: networking, hp, mobile-broadband

HP hs3110 HSPA+ Mobile Broadband Module do not work after fresh Ubuntu install. *lsusb* shows that there is broadband module, but network manager can not see it. Maybe someone had this problem. This module is old and I can see on HP site that Ubuntu is supported http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-probook-645-g2-notebook-pc/8430750/document/c04926493#AbT5 . Please ask what more info do you need and I will put it here.

```
##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 007: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03f0:521d Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:7053 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: You could add the lsusb line. That at least give us the VID:PID with which should be easy to google for results regarding Ubuntu.

Comment: Added lsusb output.

Comment: Same here, hs3110 in an EliteBook 840 G1, Ubuntu MATE 16.04. I see the device in `lsusb` but Network Manager doesn’t find any Mobile Broadband devices. Any luck yet?

Answer (score 0):

Read about gobi-loader http://www.codon.org.uk/~mjg59/gobi_loader/ . Try this firmware (from 48568.exe): https://github.com/JoliOS/linux-firmware/tree/master/gobi  Possibly you could show usb-devices output.

Comment: I know that earlier devices (such as the GOBI2000) needed this step to load a binary firmware blob, but that this should be necessary with the hs3110 is news to me. The two URLs you are posting also just mention the Gobi devices—do you have any sources to confirm whether this is necessary with the hs3110?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research, I found that apparently the OP has come across a way to get it to work, which I’ve summarized into an answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/965442/149408